# What is the correct mapping of Mid-Atlantic timezone in momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

What is the mapping of Mid-Atlantic timezone in momentjs? I have searched on stackoverflow for the correct mapping in momentjs but could not find a suitable answer.

[image]

Comment: Check the Timezones [list](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Comment: I have already checked the list but could not find suitable mapping

Comment: Then you are looking for something that doesn't exists..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a timezone identifier for UTC -2:00 to use with moment-timezone, try `America/Noronha` or `Atlantic/South_Georgia`

Comment: Mid-Atlantic uses UTC -2:00 and UTC -1:00.  In DST it uses UTC -1:00.Above are for UTC -2:00 only

Comment: The IANA timezone database doesn't appear to contain a timezone that behaves that way.  

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Please cite your source that indicates that such a timezone exists.

Comment: here is the link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms912391(v=winembedded.11)

Comment: The Mid-Alantic timezone (index 075) in that list indicates UTC -2:00 and says nothing about DST.  According to the IANA tz list, DST is not observed in that timezone.